# Get email content by gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, gmail-addons

I am trying to get gmail content(body) like Wrike(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qftV.jpg) but getting the above error.

"Access denied: : Not allowed for full access to mail message"

```
Logger.log(mail.getPlainBody());
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code it seems to me that you need to include in your
"appsscript.json" file the correct scope.

```
// This scope allows you to: 'View your email messages and settings'
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"]

// This scope gives you full access to your Gmail - 'Read, send, delete, and manage your email'
"oauthScopes": ["https://mail.google.com/"]
```

see the scope documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#gmailv1

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
I replaced scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata" with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly"

Note: scope was not added, it was replaced. With both entries, it seemed to revert to the lower permission scope (metadata) rather than the higher one (readonly).

Got the scope information I needed here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/scopes

Answer (score 0):

Also try adding the body with the following section,

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue()
.setTopLabel('Body')
.setContent(mail.getBody()));
```

Worked for me.